# Multiple loop calls with coroutines

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I need to make several calls in parallel and only send the result when everything is successful with coroutines

I want to call several pages at once. Because the API has 4 pages and I want to bring the result all at once.

I managed to do it manually like this:

```
private fun fetchList() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val item1 = async { repository.getList(1)!! }
        val item2 = async { repository.getList(2)!! }
        val item3 = async { repository.getList(3)!! }
        val item4 = async { repository.getList(4)!! }

        launch {
            mutableLiveDataList.success(item1.await() + item2.await() + item3.await() + item4.await())
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to loop it, it just brings up one of the pages.

Api:

```
@GET("cards")
suspend fun getListCards(@Query("set") set: String, @Query("page") page: Int): CardsResponse
```

Comment: Are you sure the other pages are not empty? Also the "API" you posted is not the same as the one used in fetchList.

Comment: In my viewmodel he shows the total and says that the right amount is coming.

The name of the api is different, because I called the service in the repository and the name of the function ended up putting it like this.

suspend fun getList(page: Int) : List<Card>?{
        return apiService.getListCards("2ED", page).cards
    }

Comment: Your code looks correct to me. Put breakpoints there and see what repository.getList(2) is returning.

Comment: Your last (nested) `launch` is redundant. The same coroutine can start the async tasks and await on them in the end.

Comment: Also, you can simplify this code using `pageNumbers.map { async { repository.getList(it} } }.awaitAll()`. You do have to wrap in `supervisorScope` or `coroutineScope` depending on how you want failure of one of the fetches to impact the rest.

Answer (score 3):

I did as [@curioustechizen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/570930/curioustechizen) said and it worked.

Here's an example of how it looks:

```
private fun fetchList() {
    viewModelScope.launch {

        val listPageNumbers = arrayListOf<Int>()
        (1..4).forEach { listPageNumbers.add(it) }

        listPageNumbers.map {
            delay(1000)
            async {
                mutableLiveDataList.success(repository.getListCards(it)!!)
            }
        }.awaitAll()
    }
}
```

Comment: You could simplify it even further: you don't need the `listPageNumbers` variable at all. `(1..4).map { }` should work.